# JQuery .trigger click event not working under IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using the following code to route click events on an img tag to an input radio below it. The code works perfectly on Chrome and other browsers, but on IE (specifically IE 11) I must double click to get the radio selected instead of just single click to get the radio input selected. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, missing here? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#Img1').click(function() {
          $('#radio1').trigger('click');
       });
   });
</script> 




      <div class="imagesPrev col four center">
        <label class="label_radio images" for="radio1">
      <div class="labelText">
            <img id="Img1"src="image1.gif" alt="Image 1" />
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" value="image1"/>      
      </div>
      <div style="height:10px;"></div>
             Image Title <br/>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Notes:
- I also noticed that I don't have to double click as normal double click, but it has to be two clicks. Meaning one click then I can wait for like 10-15 seconds then do the 2nd click to get the click event routed to the radio input.

Comment: As displayed, your example does not appear to require the jQuery code at all (http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/uuLxm/1/). If anything your code may be causing the problems. Can you please show your real page with multiple controls?

Comment: ...without a full document to view, as well as an explanation, pretty hard to trouble shoot. does the image cover the input entirely? i think i have your solution, just trying to understand why you did what you did....

Comment: I have to commit it also does work for me(copied your example). Tested in IE11. You have to create a JSFiddle to show a situation it does not work.

Comment: Hi @Mchan 
could you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a `label` tag with a `for` attribute for this feature instead, this could solve your problem and be more browser compatible.

```
<label for="radio1"><img id="Img1"src="image1.gif" alt="Image 1" /></label>
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" value="image1"/>
```

I can understand if this doesn't achieve what you need, but using this method should work using HTML markup instead of jQuery

relatively horrible jsfiddle demoing this:
http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/d25KS/

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. With this approach neither click nor double click works.

Comment: bizarre, can you post a jsfiddle that has your implementation of this to see if it's something to do with the way you're having to use the HTML

Comment: I've added all html surrounding the radio input and img

Comment: I've added your HTML layout to a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/K6tzq/) and it works. When you click on the image the label does its job and selects the right radio button, so not sure why it wouldn't work for you in your current implementation. The jQuery part isn't actually required, but added it in to test the suggestion by @TrueBlueAussie and then commented it out.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/89wTk/

You should use [.prop();](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) when dealing with checkbox/radio inputs.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#Img1').click(function() {
           var checkBox = $("#radio1");
           checkBox.prop("checked", !checkBox.prop("checked"));
       });
   });
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but it is not working under IE 11

Comment: It is, I've tested it O_o. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Weird, I've updated the jquery version in the fiddle and here's a SS of it working in IE11... http://i.imgur.com/J8m38xB.png

Comment: btw when I say it is not working, this does not mean it is not accepting clicks. It means I still have to double click on the img to get the radio selected

Comment: Actually I can't figure out till now why specially double click?!! That's really weird

Comment: It's toggling on a single click for me

Comment: incidentally, you should use `.prop()` when dealing with properties and `.attr()` for attributes. inputs can have both of these, so it's not specifically using `.prop()` on `inputs`. Pedantic, I know. I haven't quite figured out the difference between a property and an attribute of an element yet, but with `checked` you are right using `.prop()`

Comment: Maybe I should consider revising and saying to use prop() when dealing with checked properties on radios/checkboxes. Still don't get the downvote though since the answer technically works.

Comment: Tried using .prop() and it didn't work at all, not with a click nor with double click

Comment: I also noticed that I don't have to double click as we usually double click, but it has to be two clicks. Meaning one click then I can wait for like 10-15 seconds then do the 2nd click to get it selected. Which makes the problem so weird as it is not understandable why 2 separate clicks to route the click event

Answer (score 1):

I remember that some version of IE don't support clicking objects other than links or buttons :(

Perhaps try using:

```
$("#radio1").checked(true);
```

or

```
$("#radio1").selected(true);
```

as a work around

Comment: Tried both checked, selected but none of them worked. I don't get any response while using them either on click or double click

Answer (score 1):

Just simple, you don't have to use any Jquery for this, just keep everything inside the `label`:

```
<label for="radio_btn">
   <img id="img"src="image1.gif" alt="Image here" />
   <input type="radio" id="radio_btn" name="radio1" value="image1"/>
</label>
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/fals/3phf4/

Comment: There was an earlier answer with the same approach, and based on the code in my question it didn't work. Please note that I am tied to the code in my question

Comment: @MChan This works fine in my IE10 too. Does the demo supplied by Fals not work in your IE11? (If it works, something else is going on that you are not telling us!) By the way, since the radio button is nested inside the `<label>` this also works without the `for` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/C2j7t/

Answer (score 1):

Your code example works fine in IE11 (desktop and metro).  Is it possible that there is another click event on the page that is capturing and preventing the click event on the image?  Maybe something is causing the page to lose focus (first click gets window focus second clicks the image)?  Try putting an alert in the click function to see if the click is getting registered.  If that's not the issue, try running the body of the function in the console to see if that is the issue.  You might try other ways to trigger the event, as suggested by others.  Or try the jQuery .triggerHandler("click") method.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be with your markup. You have your image and click events inside a label.

According to w3schools:
"...if the user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles the control."
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

That toggle is perhaps messing with your javascript. Try moving the markup outside of the label and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

That's an easy one :).

The #img1 is encapsulated inside the

```
<label class="label_radio images" for="radio1">
```

So, without the jQuery part it's already working. Now when having the jQuery part, a single click will become a double click:
1) 'for' element of label_radio
2) the trigger in jQuery part

So, for x-browser, you should not wrap the img inside the label.
Or try to cancel the event in $('#Img1').click(function(event) { ...

Answer (score 1):

You have both your `img` and `radio` wrapped in `label`.
HTML's default behavior is that click on label triggers radio/checkbox inside.

There are two ways you can solve your problem:

1. Remove javascript function altogether.
2. If there's additional reason for javascript, change your html markup, and move radio outside of the label. Also remove `for` attribute, cause it triggers radio selection. Something like this:

   ```
   <div class="imagesPrev col four center">
       <label class="label_radio images">
           <div class="labelText">
               <img id="Img1"src="image1.gif" alt="Image 1" />
           </div>
       </label>
       <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio1" value="image1"/>      
       <div style="height:10px;"></div>
       Image Title
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('click','.Img1',function()
   {
      var checkBox = $(".radio1");
      checkBox.prop("checked", !checkBox.prop("checked"));
   });
</script>

<img class="Img1" src="image1.gif" alt="Image 1" />
<input type="radio" class="radio1" name="radio1" value="image1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue and its very weird .... the workaround that is working for me is that instead of using the trigger function .. put the code which is executed in the trigger click event in a javascript function and call that function instead of trigger event ... example is given below. 
For this example i will use an alert in case of a click on the element with id radio1.

```
Event definition
$('#radio1').on('click',function () {
alert("Hi");
})
So Instead of using $('#radio1').trigger('click'); we can put the alert in a javascript function and call the javascript function where ever i am calling the trigger click event.

Javascript function 

function triggerClick(){
alert("Hi")
}

and just call this function(triggerClick()) where ever you are using $('#radio1').trigger('click');
```

Please let me know if this is helpfull

Answer (score -1):

Try to use **.click()** instead of .trigger('click'):

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Img1').click(function() {
            $('#radio1').click();
        });
    });
</script>`

it should work, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info

Comment: `.click()` when called on a jQuery object like in this code, is simply a shorthand for `.trigger("click")`. to access the underlying dom object you can use `.get(0)`  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Here's the source responsible for the jquery `.click()` btw. See line 6 and 14: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/7877c4fa73120bc6d21a5fcd302a896f03b23876/src/event/alias.js#L6-L16